# How to tell if a MFC Dialog has been created/initialized?

Tags: c++, mfc, winapi

I have an OnMove handler in my dialog class, which does some stuff with control objects (i.e a CButton). I'm finding this handler gets called before the dialog OnInitDialog method is called, and hence when I try to call methods on the child controls, I get ASSERTS in debug as the controls don't yet exist... they are created in OnInitDialog.

There's two things I'd like to be able to check:

1. How do I tell the dialog has been initialized?
2. How do I check an individual CWnd control object's window has been created?

In both cases I'm looking for class members or method call results that can be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Set a flag in `OnInitDialog`
2. Use your dialog's `m_hWnd`:

   ```
   if ( ::IsWindow(m_Ctrl.m_hWnd) ) {
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: I don't want to write custom code, so 2 sounds preferable. Are there any other members I could test?

Comment: GetSafeHwnd() but it's just a wrapper around ::IsWindow(). In term of object-orientedness I guess it's nicer than querying the handle manually - I like the 'low-level' control of inspecting the handle, personally.

Comment: `GetSafeHwnd()` isn't a wrapper around `IsWindow()` - it's a wrapper around `m_hWnd` - non-standard c++ to test if `this` is null, and return either `m_hWnd` or `null`.  `m_hWnd` can be not-null while not being a window (just as a file handle can be not null but the file be closed)